# Excel issue with "=TODAY()" and adding it to another cell with other values

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

As you can see below I'm unable to get the =TODAY() "correct" information over to another column. And I'm really hoping that there is some way to actually get this to work.

I'm fairly new to excel so I'm just using a `=column&column&column` etc.

I'm trying to get DDMMYYYY data correctly into column "B".
I'm currently just using a basic formula`"=F11&C11&G11&D11&H11&E11&I11&O11&P11&J11&K11&E11&L11&D11&Q11&E11&R11&M11&N11&E11&S11&B1"` where O11 is where i have the DDMMYYYY.

Comment: It isn't obvious where you are using today, but your problem is the way Excel stores dates.  They are stored internally as a day count since a reference date, and then displayed in readable form using formatting.  If you just concatenate the cell value, it will use the raw number as stored internally.  You need to use functions to display the date the way you want it in the string.  Add the detail of how you need the date displayed to the question.

Comment: Could you possibly point me in an direction where I can try and understand how the function should look?

Comment: I can try to be a little more clear. This is how I am currently trying to get it to work "=F11&C11&G11&D11&H11&E11&I11&O11&P11&J11&K11&E11&L11&D11&Q11&E11&R11&M11&N11&E11&S11&B1" and the O11 is the =TODAY() function that i'm trying to interact with the "main" column.

Comment: Any answer will guide you there or provide a solution, but people need to know what appearance the date should be in order to know what function(s) would be appropriate.  e.g., "04/15/2018" would need a different solution than "Sunday April 15".  What format are you using in the TODAY() cell?

Comment: It needs to be the current DDMMYYYY.
So the formatting for the cell is just DDMMYYYY.
If that makes any sense? I'm fairly new to the excel world.

Comment: @B.Frederik,,, Excel never Produces Current date in such format as you have written, when used =TOday(). And in Cell O11, if you get value  15042018 after you have used Concatenate then the Value is just a number is not a date and since it's a numeric value then the format doesn't supports the TEXT command. It simply need a different approach that is ,, how to convert number into date? "I can provide a perfect Solution to you to do so, but first confirm that my perception is correct and you are looking for the same to do."

Comment: @B.Frederik, if we hadn't discovered the strange activity with the function wizard, the next step would have been using date functions to format the cell reference. Please don't be confused by Rajesh's comment above.  The TEXT function is designed for exactly that purpose (and obviously works). But if he wants to produce an alternate solution, your testing it might shed some light on your system's strange behavior.  For example, if functions other than TEXT also don't work unless you use the function wizard, it might suggest that your Excel installation is corrupted (in which case, reinstall).

Comment: Sure. Just to note. I actually tried on 4 computers total and I couldn't get it to work on either. Tried on my laptop as I recall it has 2014 excel? My mothers runs office 365. Tried on the office tried both office 365 and office 2003. And on my home computer I tried as well. I also tried saving it in a different version as you suggested. :) Thanks again a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Background**

Excel stores dates and times in units of days.  The date is stored as the (integer) count of days since January 0, 1900; we passed day 43,000 in September of last year.  Time is appended to the date as the decimal fraction of a day (noon is 0.5 day).

Date (and time) information is displayed in readable form by formatting it.  There is a collection of built-in formats to display date and time information in commonly used forms.  Excel also includes a collection of functions that let you extract and use the common date and time components.

If you simply refer to a date or time value in a cell, you will be working with the raw internal representation rather than the formatted version displayed.  That's why your TODAY() value is displayed formatted as DDMMYYYY (15042018), but your reference to that cell produces a value of 43205.  If you want to use a DDMMYYYY translation of the cell value in your string, you need to convert the raw cell value to that form.

**Solution**

The simplest solution may be to use the TEXT function and include the format spec.  The TEXT function converts a numerical value to a formatted representation of the value.  It can translate Excel date/time values to readable forms as well as format other kinds of numbers.  A useful guide to the TEXT function: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c

In your worksheet, cell O11 is the cell with the TODAY() function.  Instead of concatenating the raw cell reference (`...&O11&...`), replace the cell reference with

```
TEXT(O11,"ddmmyyyy")
```

like `...&TEXT(O11,"ddmmyyyy")&...`

That formats the value of TODAY() in your string to the DDMMYYYY format.

**Version Issue**

Note that the problems you describe in the comments are due to selecting an ancient Excel format for the file.  You're using Excel V2016, but selected a file format limited to V97-2003.  That format isn't capable of features more recent than the 2003 version.  The TEXT function dates back to V2007, and it's surprising that you haven't run into other unsupported features.

Save the file as "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook", close it, open the saved version, then put in the TEXT function.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76072/discussion-on-answer-by-fixer1234-excel-issue-with-today-and-adding-it-to-a).

Comment: @DavidPostill, you may need to give the OP posting permission in chat (rep of 1).

Comment: He automatically gets privileges for that room :)

Comment: Excel 2003 perfectly supports the TEXT() function.